# Adobe Air SDK, problems with ADL

Tags: html, sdk, air, adobe

I have just entered the world of Adobe Air, and I wanted to make a simple `HTML-test-app` with Adobe Air SDK.

I downloaded the SDK for Mac from [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html)

I followed the [guide](http://help.adobe.com/it_IT/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ecc.html) to create a simple `html-app`

the problem , now , is that I should use ADL to start the app from the command line. But I have no idea of how to run the executable ADL

thanks

Comment: I have to create an environment variable I think .. that points to the folder where there is the ADL executable

Comment: I created an environment variable to the path of the folder adobe_air 

more info [here](http://help.adobe.com/it_IT/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-71994050128cca87097-8000.html)